# I see one backslash, but there are actually two backslashes!

Tags: bash, libreoffice, paste

Does anyone can help me to understand that weird issue?

I was trying to rename a very long list of folders.

I went to the parent directory and listed all the folders to rename in a text file:

```
find PARENT_FOLDER/ -type d -name *Images > ~/Desktop/directory_listing
```

I opened the list file in LibreOffice Calc, modified what I had to modify, used the "concatenate" function to make a command for each folder to rename, etc.

When I came back to CLI and pasted my commands from Calc, mv fails stating that it can't find the folders to rename. Well, the folders actually exist but after further investigations, I discovered that the pasted text from Calc shows 1 backlash on screen but actually contains 2! 
So, the text I paste into bash is something as:

```
mv Test\ Folder-1-Images TestFolder1
```

But what it actualy interprets is:

```
mv Test\\ Folder-1-Images TestFolder1
```

I confirmed that with gedit, where my command line in the text shows 1 backslash, but if I copy and paste it into a search box within gedit, it shows 2!

Why? And how to fix/prevent that?

Comment: Mildly curious: What modifications did you make? If they follow some pattern, we might be able to use shell commands to do them and ditch LibreOffice.

Comment: I believe this has to do with escaping spaces. This should help you complete your task: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108635/why-i-cant-escape-spaces-on-a-bash-script

Comment: I know this is not your question per se, but take a look at `xargs` used with piping. With this you can do what you wanted to do in the first place waaay more easily. And it's really to use.

Comment: Other way around: There's actually one backslash, but you need to type two to refer to it literally.

Answer (score 6):

## In Linux shells `\` is a special character

**It tells the shell interpreter to treat the next character literally**

that is, if you want to pass `\` as part of the command in a script, you have to use it twice. The first `\` is interpreted as a special character by the shell that tells the shell not to treat the next character, in this case the second `\` not as a special character and pass it on.

In other situations a `\` followed by a normal character is treated as an `escape sequence` that gives the combination special use. For example, `\n` takes the pointer to is a new line.

See http://linuxcommand.org/wss0060.php for other examples.

Also see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html for more explanations.

Hope this helps